# Storing class information in a dictionary or something similar

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im sorry if this is a duplicate question, but i did a search and was unable to find info on what i was looking for. If you know of a qusetion to refer too, please link me!

But anyways, i have a function creating a class

```
private Item CreateItem(string name, bool stackable, int amount, string discription)
{
    Item item = new Item(name, stackable, amount, discription);
    return item;
}
```

Then i have another function that finds the stats

```
private Item findItemStats(string name)
{
    if (name == "Gold")
        return CreateItem(name, false, 0, "Gold Bar");

    return null;
}
```

This is what im using to add the item too the inventory

```
  internal void addItem(string name)
    {
        var item = findItemStats(name);
        if (item == null)
            Debug.LogError("Item not found!");
        Instance.itemsToAdd.Add(item);
        if (!inventory())
            return;
        if (inventory().activeInHierarchy)
        {
            placeItemsOnInventory();
            sortItems();
        }
```

My question is, whats a better way to store and retrieve the data of item stats. I at one point hosted a private server and on that, the item stats were stored in a .txt (or json w/e) and then would have a class for taking that data and placing it to the item that was being called. Was just curious of a way to either do that, or a way to store the data in a separate class/file with easy access and placement of the item data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a fairly wide open topic and depends on your needs. The simplest option if you are just saving something locally is using `PlayerPrefs`

### PlayerPrefs Example:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player Score", 10);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
//And to fetch:
var playerScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player Score");
```

[More on using PlayerPrefs](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/672869/player-prefs-to-store-high-scores.html)

### Serialization Example Snippet.

For something more complex you can serialize your data to a data format such as XML, JSON, binary, CSV or any data that you want to import.This is an example of binary.

```
public void SaveData()
{
    if (!Directory.Exists("Saves"))
        Directory.CreateDirectory("Saves");
        
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream saveFile = File.Create("Saves/save.binary");
    LocalCopyOfData = PlayerState.Instance.localPlayerData;
    formatter.Serialize(saveFile, LocalCopyOfData);
    saveFile.Close();
}
public void LoadData()
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream saveFile = File.Open("Saves/save.binary", FileMode.Open);
    LocalCopyOfData = (PlayerStatistics)formatter.Deserialize(saveFile);
    saveFile.Close();
}
```

[More on Saving and Loading player data](https://www.sitepoint.com/saving-and-loading-player-game-data-in-unity/)

### SqlLite

Alternatively you can use tooling for integrating a sqlite db into your project. The code for this looks like a standard db connection in .net.

```
string conn = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/PickAndPlaceDatabase.s3db"; //Path to database.
     IDbConnection dbconn;
     dbconn = (IDbConnection) new SqliteConnection(conn);
     dbconn.Open(); //Open connection to the database.
     IDbCommand dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand();
     string sqlQuery = "SELECT value,name, randomSequence " + "FROM PlaceSequence";
     dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
     IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
```

[How to Setup Sqlite withn Unity3d](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/743400/database-sqlite-setup-for-unity.html).

### Cloud Hosting

For data that needs to be persist and be made available across multiple machines. You may want to consider hosting your data on a proper database or cloud hosted data store service. Some examples:

[Unity Cloud Data is in alpha(As of 7/10/2016)](https://data.cloud.unity3d.com/#/landing)

[Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/)(Fun fact:Firebase was originally concieved to be a chat server tool for mmo's)

[Play Fab](https://playfab.com/)

[Game Sparks](http://www.gamesparks.com/?gclid=CLPFxdzzs8gCFQGTaQodfYANUQ)

[Amazon RDS](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjsgv-jvOrNAhWD7CYKHZeTDrYQFggvMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Faws.amazon.com%2Frds%2F&usg=AFQjCNE5ckJTT2h1MsledNNwOMElV4GjCA&sig2=XDAdcoHBpr77cg3TX-DvEA&bvm=bv.126130881,d.eWE&cad=rja)

[Google Cloud Datastore(MySql)](https://cloud.google.com/sql/)

[Google Cloud Database(NoSql)](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/)

[Azure Db](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/)

[back4app (thanks @Joe Blow)](https://www.back4app.com/)

[Other Data Storage options](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1078686/unity-globally-online-data-storage.html)

Googling *Backend as a service* yields lots of other goodies as well. Sky's the limit!~

Comment: This seems like saving the data after you retrieve the item. I need a way of storing the data before you get the item, so the game has a clean and easy to edit place to look for finding the initial states to place on the item (the stackable and amount may be making the use of my code confusing)

Comment: Ahh this data is still very useful and i will end up using your answer a lot, but im not sure if it's solving my original question of a place to store the data before getting the item

Comment: You can run any of the mentioned solitions on your init install or data load with the unity events. Or start with the xml\json\csv\text and then load it.

Comment: Oh yeah thats a good point, i guess i was thinking of it differently ahhh, ok i think this is what i need then!! Thanks alot man

Comment: don't forget even though parse.com is closed, there are sundry excellent Parse possibilities eg. back4app (which is pretty much identical to Parse, happily)

Answer (score 0):

Unity has Scriptable objects that can be used to store data, and the objects get stored within the assets folder so easily accessible.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects

Comment: Im aware unity can store data in prefabs. When the item is created on the scene the stats are transferred from a  stored location to the prefab. I just need a list of item data thats created before the game is started so when i add an item to my inventory, it has a place to look at that is cleaner than my current findItemStats. Because that one will be ugly after a few 100 items.

Comment: I would initially store the required info on the prefab. But that makes the prefab heavier to load (maybe not much but still mroe) Also, its easier to add the item to your game using cheat engine if the data is stored directly on the item. Also, its more complicated to edit item stats that way

Comment: Scriptable objects are not prefabs, they are a data object like a texture or audio clip. 

"This is most useful for assets which are only meant to store data."

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html